# How to return the position where an array can be split such that the sum of one side equals the other

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to check if there is a place to split the array so that the sum of the numbers on one
side is equal to the sum of the numbers on the other side return the length of the two arrays as an array but
if there is no place to split the array, return -1.

```
test('for an obvious case where the array can be split evenly', () => {
  expect(canBalance([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8])).toEqual([6, 3]);
});

test('for an obvious case where the array cannot be split evenly', () => {
  expect(canBalance([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])).toBe(-1);
});

test('for when the array has all zeros with a one at the end', () => {
  expect(canBalance([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])).toBe(-1);
});

test('for when the array has all ones but cannot be split', () => {
  expect(canBalance([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])).toBe(-1);
});

test('for when the array has all ones but can be split', () => {
  expect(canBalance([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])).toEqual([9, 9]);
});

test('for when the array some negative numbers', () => {
  expect(canBalance([3, 18, -5, -44, 23, 26, 20, -1, 0, -10, 30])).toEqual([10, 1]);
});

test('Alternating cases of positive and negative equivalent with 1 at the end', () => {
  expect(canBalance([-10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10,
    -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, 1])).toBe(-1);
});

test('for a simple case of positive and negative numbers', () => {
  expect(canBalance([1, 0, 0, -1])).toBe(-1);
});

test('for a tricky case of decimal numbers', () => {
  expect(canBalance([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])).toBe(-1);
});
```

My approach so far has been to get to total in a variable. Then add up from array[0] up to array.length-1 and compare each time with total/2.

```
function canBalance(array) {
  //Type your solutions here
  var arrayAdd = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i<array.length-1; i++) {
    arrayAdd+=array[i];
  }
  var total = 0;
  for(var j=0; j<array.length-1; j++)  {
    total+=array[j];
    if(total==arrayAdd/2) {
      return [j+1, array.length-j-1];
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
module.exports = canBalance;
```

I believe it should work. But, it keeps failing for a lot of the tests

Comment: at a glance it looks ok to me, but I know from experience how easy it can be to miss a subtle bug :) Which test cases is it failing for?

Comment: I just used those tests as examples. I edited the actual tests i ran.

Comment: Only the second and the last 2 worked

Comment: ok, thanks - but what are the actual results from the test cases that fail?

Comment: Random Results. I seem to be getting -1 mostly where i should get actual results and actual values where i should get -1. Like its inverted or something

Comment: It can't be "random" - your algorithm is perfectly deterministic. I appreciate you mean that you can't see any rhyme or reason in the results - but I'm afraid I'm not willing to start debugging until I can see the incorrect output you're actually getting.

Comment: First -1
Third - [1,26]

Comment: Fourth -- [8,9]
Fifth -- [-1]

Comment: thanks, and now I take a closer look I see the problem straight away. I don't think this is worth putting into an answer - but it's the ending condition in your `for` loops: `i<array.length-1`. This should be `i<array.length`. (The same on the second loop.) You're missing off the final element of the array when you're computing the total. Apologies for not looking closely enough to catch it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You could build the an array with the sums of all elements from the start and check if from the end adjacent sums exists, thehn exit with the counts, otherwise return `-1`.

> ```
> array 1, 1, 1, 2, 1
> sums  1  2  3  5  6  left
> sums           3  1  right
>             ^  ^     result [3, 2]
> ```

```js
function canBalance(array) {
    var left = array.map((s => v => s += v)(0)),
        right = 0;
        i = array.length;

    while (i--) {
        right += array[i];
        if (right === left[i - 1]) return [i, array.length - i];
    }
    return -1;
}

console.log(canBalance([1, 1, 1, 2, 1])); // [3, 2]
console.log(canBalance([2, 1, 1, 2, 1])); // -1
console.log(canBalance([10, 10]));        // [1, 1]

console.log(canBalance([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8])); // [6, 3]
console.log(canBalance([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])); // -1
console.log(canBalance([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])); // -1
console.log(canBalance([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])); // -1
console.log(canBalance([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])); // [9, 9]
console.log(canBalance([3, 18, -5, -44, 23, 26, 20, -1, 0, -10, 30])); // [10, 1]
console.log(canBalance([-10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, 1])); // -1
console.log(canBalance([1, 0, 0, -1])); // -1
console.log(canBalance([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])); // -1
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: array.map((s => v => s += v)(0)),

Comment: Please... Explain this

Comment: What if i do s=0;
array.map(v=>s+=v)

Comment: that takes a closure over `s` with zero and works as accumulator. the above line works as well.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using reduce

1. Loop array by reduce
2. Calculate total of array by another reduce only once
3. Calculate forward and backward totals at each index and assign to accumulator objects - forward and backward index with index of total
4. Check whether half of total index exists in forward and backward objects

Working code reference

```js
function canBalance(arr){
   let result = arr.reduce((acc, v, i, self) =>{
      acc.tot = acc.tot || self.reduce((ac, val) => ac + val)
      acc.forward = acc.forward || {};
      acc.backward = acc.backward || {};   
      acc.forward.tot = acc.forward.tot? acc.forward.tot + v : 0 + v;
      acc.forward[acc.forward.tot] = i+1;
      
      acc.backward.tot = acc.backward.tot? acc.backward.tot + self[self.length -i -1] : 0 + self[self.length -i -1];
      acc.backward[acc.backward.tot] = i+1;
      return acc
                     },{});
  //console.log(result)
  if(result.tot !== 0 && result.forward[result.tot/2] && result.backward[result.tot/2]){
    return [result.forward[result.tot/2], result.backward[result.tot/2]]
  }else{
    return -1
  }
}

console.log(canBalance([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]));
console.log(canBalance([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]));
console.log(canBalance([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]))
console.log(canBalance([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
console.log(canBalance([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
console.log(canBalance([3, 18, -5, -44, 23, 26, 20, -1, 0, -10, 30]));
console.log(canBalance([-10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10,-10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, -10, +10, 1]));
console.log(canBalance([1, 0, 0, -1]));
console.log(canBalance([0.1, 0.2, 0.3]));
```

codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aboYNjE?editors=1010

Comment: yes @NinaScholz, may be :) ... just upvoted your solution for the approach and effort